# How to Read only the last line of a text file in Lua?

Tags: file, lua, io

I have a program that generates text fiels that can be up to 20 mets in size. Sometimes I only care about the last line in the file, is there a way to read just that line with out wasting memory reading the rest of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could be mistaken but without resorting to some trickery, it seems that you can't.
However, if you have a rough estimate of the length of the lines, you can open a file and then seek from the end, say, 1Kb.

```
local f = io.open([[c:\test_file.txt]], "r")
local len = f:seek("end")

f:seek("set", len - 1024)
local text = f:read("*a")

print(string.match(text, "[^%c]*$"))
f:close()
```

Hope this helps. Take into account that the pattern needs some refinement. It currently assumes that no control characters appear on a line. If your line has i.e. tabs, then it will capture from there till the end of file.

Comment: The two seek lines can easily be combined into one: f:seek("end", -1024)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how this will behave with with files containing really big lines since it will make lots of `f:read(1)` calls. I've also added an optional parameter to read more than just a single line.

```
-- assumes file ends with line break
function lastline(path, how_many)
    how_many = (how_many) or 1
    how_many = how_many + 1

    local f = assert(io.open(path))
    local new_lines_found = 0
    
    -- needs to find at least a pair of \n
    local len = f:seek("end")
    for back_by=1, len do
        f:seek("end", -back_by)
        if f:read(1) == '\n' then
            new_lines_found = new_lines_found + 1
            if new_lines_found == how_many then
                local last_lines = f:read("a")
                io.write(last_lines)
                return
            end
        end
    end

    f:close()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest solution I could come up with.

```lua
local function readLastLine(filePath)
    local file = io.open(filePath, "rb")
    local eof  = file:seek("end")
    
    for i = 1, eof do
        file:seek("set", eof - i)
        if i == eof then break end
        if file:read(1) == '\n' then break end
    end
    
    local lastLine = file:read("*a")
    file:close()
    return lastLine
end
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).