# Proper code for reading the 1st 10 lines of a file into a Lua table?

Tags: lua

I'm just learning Lua and my book (*Programming in Lua*) has a bit of code in it that "reads the first 10 lines of a file:"

```
a = {}
for i=1,10 do
    a[#a+1] = io.read()
end
```

This doesn't really make any sense to me; doesn't this read ten nil values? Could someone please explain this?

Comment: `io.read()` is equivalent to `io.read("*l")`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Read only the last line of a text file in Lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497311/how-to-read-only-the-last-line-of-a-text-file-in-lua)

Answer (score 3):

Short version: It boils down to whether `io.input` was called earlier in code that isn't listed in your question. If it was called, it'll print the first 10 lines of that file (explained in detail below). If it wasn't called earlier and you're running from the command line or interactively, it'll print the first 10 lines that you type into the console once that code executes. For other cases, it just depends on how the app is launched.

The [Lua 5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1) reference manual for `io.read` says the following:

> io.read (···)
>
> Equivalent to io.input():read.

And the documentation for `io.input` says:

> When called with a file name, it opens the named file (in text mode), and sets its handle as the default input file. When called with a file handle, it simply sets this file handle as the default input file. When called without parameters, it returns the current default input file. [...]

And the documentation for `file.read` (`file` being the object returned by calling `io.input()`) says:

> Reads the file *file*, according to the given formats, which specify what to read. For each format, the function returns a string (or a number) with the characters read, or nil if it cannot read data with the specified format. When called without formats, it uses a default format that reads the entire next line [...]

So there are two possibilities here:

- `io.input` was called previously with a parameter (some code not shown in your question), setting the default input file. Calls to `io.read` with no parameters will return the "default format" of that input file, which is "the entire next line."
- `io.input` was *not* called previously with a parameter (which is true in your case if there's no additional code). Calls to `io.read` with no parameters will return "the entire next line" of the standard input, such as the user's command line input if the program is running from the command line.

In the first case, `nil` will be returned by `io.read()` after it has finished reading all the lines of the file. This could mean 10 instances of `nil` get read, but it depends on the file.

In the second case, `nil` will be returned if the standard input is exhausted, which could happen in different ways, depending on how the app is launched. This too could mean 10 instances of `nil`.